# How to get column name in select query based on column value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table1:-

```
ID  NAME    ADDRESS
1   TEST1    qwr
2   TEST2    sdf
```

I wanted to get column name in the select query based on ID column value

EX:-

If the Id=1 i want "name" column in select query 
if id=2 i want "address" column in select query

```
select name from table (when id=1)
select address from table(when id=2)
```

I hope i conveyed my query clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This query will return the results in a single column and multiple rows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN name WHEN id = 2 THEN address END AS result 
  FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries to get the two results:

```
select (select name from table where id = 1) as name,
       (select address from table where id = 2) as address;
```